# angular-cli: AoT compilation with ng serve by default

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jit, aot

In Angular CLI, `ng serve` uses JiT and the flag `--aot` is required in order to use AoT compilation.

Is it possible to make that `ng serve` uses AoT by default and JIT is only used when `--aot=false` flag is passed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Edit**: starting with angular 9, aot compilation is enabled by default in development environment ([see documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ivy#aot-and-ivy))

In angular 6, you can specify default options for the `serve` target, so you can add `aot: true` in that section and by default `ng serve` will use aot

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "project:build",
        "aot": true
      },
      "configurations": {
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is true, angular 9 enabled it by default for builds but not for the serve command:

https://github.com/angularexample/angular-9-example-app/blob/master/angular.json

Answer (score 5):

Not directly an answer to your question, but rather an alternative way of achieving the same result. In your `package.json` file, you can add a custom script which compile with AoT.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "aot": "ng serve --aot"
  },
...
```

Then you can run the command `npm aot`.